# supabase append_array using dynamic function

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I am trying to pass a column name of the table `profiles` as a parameter `which_col` into a function that utilizes [`append_array()`](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_array_append-function.php).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_item(show_id text, id uuid, which_col text)
AS
$func$
EXECUTE format('SET %I = array_append(I%, $1) where id = $2', which_col) USING show_id, id
$func$
language plpgsql;
```

I've tried several variations like returning `profiles` or `into` statements. I have little experience with sql and especially postgres. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code, there were few issues in your code which I tried to fix in this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_item(show_id text, id uuid, which_col text, val_to_append text)
RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('UPDATE profiles SET %I = array_append(%I, $1) WHERE id = $2', which_col, which_col) 
   USING val_to_append, id;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Use this function like this, but don't forget to change the dummy values with your actual values.

```
SELECT add_item('show_id_val', 'id_val', 'your_col', 'val_to_append');
```

Hope it works :)